# How to parse an object and get all its data members and fields in java?

Tags: java, json, parsing, object

- How to get member functions and fields defined in any object in java. In other words, if i pass any object then it should print all its methods and fields with their values.
- For Example, [Json parser](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) parse an object and convert into json object. How it works?
- I need similar thing to do using java. what is the way to do that? Is there any good tutorial available for this?

Comment: Read up on reflection. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: I don't understand the question. Bullet one seems to have answer "use Json". Second bullet contains that answer and seems to ask how json works, which is not exactly StackOverflow question. And third one... Asks how to implement json yourself? How to use Json in Java?

Comment: I just asking to get all methods and fields of an object in java. Thats it @Deltharis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get methods and fields of any class using reflection. Look at the `Class` class and its `getMethods()`, `getDelcaredMethods()`, `getFields()` and `getDeclaredFields()` methods.

Once you have the list of fields and methods, you can print method names and arguments, as well as field values for an instance of the class. Just use appropriate methods on the `Field` and `Method` classes.